# how to write a function in pl sgl that will do a line break every 30 characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a text editor which lets me use regular expressions to find / replace text. I have a large text file and want to insert a new line in lines which are more than 30 characters. I want the line to break after the 30th character and it doesn't matter if a word or phrase breaks or not.

Original text:

```
Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line.
This is a very very very very very long line.
This is a regular line.
```

Modified text:

```
Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line.
This is one very very very ver
y very long line.
This is a regular line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions (sample data in lines #1 - 8; query that does the job begins at line #10):

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col) as
  3  (select
  4  'Hi this is a sample text.
  5  this is a line which is really really long.
  6  This is a very very very very very long line.
  7  This is a regular line.'
  8  from dual)
  9  --
 10  select regexp_substr(col, '(.{1,30})', 1, level) as val
 11  from test
 12  connect by level <= ceil(length(col) / 30)
 13  order by level;

VAL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line which is really
 really long.
This is a very very very very
very long line.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '(.{30})'||CHR(13)||'?'||CHR(10)||'?',
         '\1'||CHR(13)||CHR(10)
       ) AS replaced_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Hi this is a sample text.
this is a line.
This is a very very very very very long line.
This is a regular line.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This line is fine.
________10________20________30________40________50________60________70________80________90
________10________20________30Should be on a new line.
This line is fine too.' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | REPLACED_VALUE                 |
> | :----------------------------- |
> | Hi this is a sample text.      |
> | this is a line.                |
> | This is a very very very very  |
> | very long line.                |
> | This is a regular line.        |
> | ------------------------------ |
> | This line is fine.             |
> | ________10________20________30 |
> | ________40________50________60 |
> | ________70________80________90 |
> | ________10________20________30 |
> | Should be on a new line.       |
> | This line is fine too.         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff8daa9003b1b28cb4b5ec7ddbabd867)*

Answer (score 0):

how do you thinks about wtrite on plsql with function if and loop

for example:

```
create or replace function line_break (p_string varchar2) return varchar2 is begin
```

loop
if (some code - substring or REGEXP_REPLACE)
end loop;
end;